# Com puedo poner esto de la siguiente manera? en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: QUIERO HACERLO DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA]

Quiero acomodarlo como se muestra en la imágen pero no se me acomoda bien, espero su respuesta gracias, soy nuevo en Flutter
anexo mi código ya que no sé como acomodarlo.

// CÓDIGO

Widget ubicacion(){
return Container(

```
child: Column(
children: [
    Text("Good Morning",
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 25,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
    ),


    Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.location_on_outlined,
          size: 25,
        ),
        Text("648 Bridge Street")
      ],
    ),
  Icon(
    Icons.face,
    size: 50,
  ),
  ],
),
```

);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que tienes todo dentro del `Column`

```
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "Good Morning",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: const [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.location_on_outlined,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    Text("648 Bridge Street"),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const Icon(
              Icons.face,
              size: 50,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! En verdad, te lo agradezco!

Comment: @GabrielGonzálezDeveloper Si se resolvio tu problema marca la respuesta como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

no entendi bien que es lo que lo que no te funciona, pareces ir por el camino correcto.
De todas formas, te muestro como lo hubiera hecho yo:

```
child: Column(
    children:[
         Row(
          children: [
            Colunm(
               children:[
                  Text("Good Morning",
                        style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                  Row(
                   children: [
                         Icon(
                             Icons.location_on_outlined,
                             size: 25,
                            ),
                         Text("648 Bridge Street")
                           ],
                       ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.face,
                    size: 50,
                   ),
                 ]
              )
          ]
        )
```

Comment: Lo quiero tal como en la imágen, y me sale diferente a la imágen, no se me acomoda, ¿Que estaré haciendo mal?

Comment: @GabrielGonzálezDeveloper Incluye la imagen actual de tu app.

Comment: @loki ya agregué la imagen